# How can you implement gis server using laravel?

Tags: laravel, web-applications, server, gis

I want to start a project where my web application would suggest best path available to reach from one destination to another.
https://github.com/eleven-lab/laravel-geo
I found above url but I really don't know how to use that above mentioned thing properly. Can someone please help me understand it?

Answer (score 0):

There are many applications to do routing in GIS.If you have ESRI, they have a network builder module. In open source you can start with OSM https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing.   Also check out OSM routing with SpatiaLite.  [https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/libspatialite/wiki?name=misc-docs](http://Docs) ( [http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/Using-Routing.pdf](http://PDF)).